# how to remove speacial characters from a string in php?

Tags: php, html, filter, special-characters

i am working on a php site

from the admin panel i am updating the data of content to be shown on a page using wysig editor

which add `<p> </p>` by default has opening and closing tags while inserting in mysql table

and when i show it on pages it comes has

```
        <?> with some black bakground
```

along the content why so how can i remove or filter it dynamically while pulling records

for example

```
      // content goes in to website
      $ a = "<p> this content </p>" ;
```

i wana display it has

```
         "this content"
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please use the preview panel. Your question doesn't make any sense as it's now.

Comment: Which WYSIWYG editor are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This

```
$a = "<p> this content </p>" ;
$var = strip_tags($a);
echo $var
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to remove HTML tags, you should use `strip_tags()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: ya i only need remove hrml tags , but in case if i need not remove tags can i hide them

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a wild guess and assume you're using TincMCE, if so, have a look at `forced_root_block` setting. This is probably set to `p`.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:forced_root_block

If you really want to go the php-way, then use one of the other answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
$string = "<h1>Heading</h1>"
$string = strip_tags($string);
$echo $tstring; // output ==> Heading
```